# Override LDAP login shell for a specific user in RHEL

Tags: linux, shell, ldap

How in RHEL do I specify /sbin/nologin shell to limit a user to SFTP access only when their shell is determined by their LDAP profile? chsh only works with passwd file users I believe.

Comment: Before I formulate an answer: Would it be ok to use a custom PAM module which isn't part of standard Red Hat distribution or is it necessary to make this work in vanilla Red Hat without any extra stuff? Are we talking about RHEL5 or RHEL6?

Comment: We use both 5 and 6.  Mostly 6.  I'll hear any answer you have, but the least customizations the better.

Comment: My grand idea was to suggest using a murky PAM module hack from ancient history: pam_if surfaced in late 90s or early 21st century and alloved conditional execution of PAM modules which in turn would have made it possible for you to use separate configuration for different users authenticated against pam_ldap.so (and then you could have overriden the shell in that with `nss_override_attribute_value loginShell`). But that's out of the question because it requires way too much patching.

Comment: Here is an idea, though: If you use nslcd, you could setup a filter rule to match only those users you'd like to block from shell access and then do some mapping/replacing magic with `nss_override_attribute_value` and attribute mapping expressions (maybe mapping the shell to some bogus value for example), see manual page for nslcd.conf and "Attribute Value Mapping" section. I've got no access to anything I could test this right now, so an actual answer must wait for a while.

Comment: Are you asking how to edit your LDAP directory to set the shell to /sbin/nologin, or how to configure sshd to allow only the sftp subsystem for users with a certain shell?  For the first one, the `chsh` command on RHEL5 and newer should edit LDAP if your system LDAP config (and LDAP server) is configured properly to allow it.